# Open file with Quick Look from command shell

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, quicklook

Mac OS X has the very convenient `open` command to open any file from the command line in the same way that the Finder would.

```
thilo$ open a.pdf
```

Is there a similar command for opening the file with Quick Look?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`qlmanage -p file` will do what you want, I think.

Comment: `qlmanage -p /PATH/TO/FILE` works like a charm. If you need more info check `man qlmanage`

Comment: Nice. I'll alias that to "ql".

Comment: I have it aliased to `qlmanage -p 2>/dev/null` to suppress error messages.

Answer (score 0):

`quicklook` is now an alias for `qlmanage -p`

```
quicklook /PATH/TO/FILE
```