# Command to quickview files (like cmd+y in finder)

Tags: mac, command-line

To open a file with the default application, I can run `open file`, is there a command that will open the quickview for a file, like if I'd selected it in finder and pressed command+y?

Comment: also, are you aware that by default the spacebar will do the same as cmd + y ?

Comment: Really? Are you sure that's the default? On my computer, space renames, but that might be because I upgraded from 10.5

Comment: interesting. By default enter (return) renamed, and space launches quicklook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open file with Quick Look from command shell](https://superuser.com/questions/93383/open-file-with-quick-look-from-command-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what os version are you running? 10.5 included a program called qlmanage which can do exactly what you want. In terminal, simply type:

> qlmanage -p [file]

For more information read [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/131923/2008/02/qlterminal.html) post.